# Getting second and third elements out of an ordered list using jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, jquery-selectors

We are trying to add a class and change the URL of the image of the second and third elements in an ordered list using jQuery. The ordered list cannot be changed into unordered list. We need a way to select two items to add the class or change the image.

```
<div class= "image-gallery"> 

 <ol class ="image-control image-flex-control">

  <li> <img src="URL"> </li>
  
  <li> <img src="URL1"> </li>
  
  <li> <img src="URL2"> </li>

 </ol>

</div>
```

We need to change the src of second and third item only. How can we select the second and third using jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with `.slice()` in foreach.

> Note: `.slice()` start from 0 (zero).

```js
$("li img").slice(1).each((key,val) => {
    $(val).attr('src','IMAGE URL')
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class= "image-gallery"> 

 <ol class ="image-control image-flex-control">

  <li> <img src="URL"> </li>
  
  <li> <img src="URL1"> </li>
  
  <li> <img src="URL2"> </li>

 </ol>

</div>
```

Comment: ```.slice()``` work everywhere you using javascript. if you want change image without foreach just use ```$("li img").slice(WHICH IMG).attr('src','IMAGE URL')```